# How do I add a submodule, but overwrite a file on host repo?

Tags: git, git-submodules, hugo

I would like to have [hugoBasicExample](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugoBasicExample) as a submodule in mytheme/exampleSite. Problem is, I need to edit `config.toml` to make it a working example.

How can I mix one file in to a submodule?

Comment: You can't: a submodule that lives under `mytheme/exampleSite/` can only contain files that live within `mytheme/exampleSite/`. You can include *instructions* telling people to add something to their `config.toml`, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- fork the [`github.com/gohugoio/hugoBasicExample`](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugoBasicExample) repository (on GitHub side)
- modify the `config.toml`
- add that fork (that you as a submodule in your `mytheme` repository, as `exampleSite`)